# Manga in which the female lead lives with her father and step sister, but is kicked out and made to move to the old house where the male lead lives

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There’s a manga I read and never finished, and I don’t know the name of it. I read the manga on my phone on Tappytoon or a similar site. I think it's a fantasy type where someone got teleported into a book.

The female lead has either blonde or white hair and she lives with her father and step sister. They kicked her out and made her move to the old house where the male lead lives. Everyone thinks the male lead is dead so she was basically a widow before even getting married. Then he just shows up on day in the little rocking chair by the fireplace.

Again I really don't remember much. This is an *awful* explanation of what I remember but anyone and I mean *anyone* who knows anything about this manga please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure it's [My Unexpected Marriage](https://tapas.io/series/my-unexpected-marriage/info).

The MC, Laritte Brumayer, is not transmigrated nor reincarnated. She just is a poor character in her own life.

Laritte's sister was supposed to get married to male lead (ML) but since he allegedly betrayed the crown, and supposedly died, she had her step sister marry him.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this story?

Comment: Nothing up until the most recent chapter. I read a ton of otome isekai/romfan manwha, the one I wrote about has that specific setting about the rocking chair and the MC living in the MC house by herself.

Comment: For future reference, in order for a question to be on-topic here, it must be related to science fiction or fantasy in some way. If a question is judged to be off-topic, we close it so that it cannot receive answers. This question was initially closed then reopened, because the OP edited it to indicate that the manga they're looking for involved transmigration. But if you or anyone else thinks the correct answer doesn't involve transmigration, or any other sci-fi or fantasy element, then that answer should not be posted, since it potentially rewards the OP for posting an off-topic question.

Comment: @LogicDictates - If this turns out to be the right answer, it'll still be on-topic because OP originally thought that it was on-topic. But the answer should still be added.

Comment: @LogicDictates Mangaupdates gives it the "dragon" tag, as well as "Mythical beast", and "lost power" (although that might just be political power). This might actually be on-topic. I have not read any of it; it's possible that's all just background mythology or something.

Comment: @Valorum - So a question doesn't need to be related to sci-fi or fantasy to be on-topic? The OP just has to have _said_ it does at some point, even it that later turns out not to be true? Seems like a very exploitable loophole.

Comment: @qazmlpok - The comments from the both OP and the answerer suggest that this story (if it's the right answer) doesn't include any actual dragons or other mythical beasts. I guess one of us would have to check the story ourselves to be sure, but in the meantime, I'm inclined to place more weight on what the OP and (especially) the answerer had to say about this story than those tags.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Our [very crappy policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12170/is-a-story-identification-question-on-topic-if-it-doesnt-include-genre-defining) is that OP merely needs to *assert* that it's on-topic and we have to consider it to be on-topic

Comment: @Valorum - Thanks for the link, however the answers to that question don't address what our attitude should towards non-sci-fi/fantasy answers. And moreover, instances where such an answer is confirmed to be the correct answer. I can see the argument for giving the benefit of the doubt towards questions, although I lean your way in that regard, but even if I leaned the other way, it doesn't follow that we should welcome non-sci-fi/fantasy answers.

Comment: I may ask a question about this in meta myself, if this specific scenario hasn't been discussed already.

Comment: @LogicDictates: I quickly went through the officially available 47 chapters and I can confirm that there are NO sci-fi nor fantasy elements. The story is set in a 1700s world that's clearly not Earth, but no other elements like magic or far fetched science.

Comment: @Kadath - Laurel has pointed out in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64252112#64252112) that dragons are indicated to exist in the world this manhwa is set in, in chapter 9. I had a look for myself and can confirm that.

Comment: @LogicDictates just checked and you are right. My mind must have completely glossed over that detail.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYKiU.png - Dragons, magic, mana, dragon tears that compel the consumer to speak only truth, etc etc. Definitely fantasy genre